# Quicker way to print directories with a trailing slash if directory has children?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a list of paths, some of which don't have any subdirectories, and some do, like so:

```
foo
bar/foo
baz/burr/ham
```

I want to return a list of those paths such that the directories with children have a trailing slash appended, and the childless directories don't. So the result would look like:

```
foo
bar/
baz/
```

So far, I've used a for loop with split to split the string by forward slashes, and then access the first element of the split result, like so:

```
for path in path_list:
    spl = path.split('/')
        if len(spl) > 1:
            neat_path = spl[0] + '/'
        else:
            neat_path = spl[0]
```

This works, but I feel like there must be a neater way, or a one-liner that I'm missing.

I'd like to avoid adding too many dependencies - I'm using os.path, but don't want to use pathlib or re for this reason. If there's a quicker way using path or native Python functions, I'd love any suggestions.

Comment: Try path.partition('/'), then spl[0]+spl[1] directly.

Comment: That works, thank you! I've reduced the code down to `neat_path = ''.join(path.partition('/')[0:2])` :)